# How to config multiple Eureka Servers from client in Spring Cloud

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

From the spring doc, I see we can have peer eureka server together, so for Eureka1, in application.yml, I can have:

```
spring:
  profiles: peer1
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: peer1
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://peer2/eureka/
```

And in Eureka Server 2, I can have:

```
spring:
  profiles: peer2
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: peer2
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://peer1/eureka/
```

Now these two eureka servers are aware each other, it is good.
BUT, now in configuring client, when they register again Eureka, how to do this?

In my client application, I have:

```
eureka:
      instance:
        hostname: ${host.instance.name:localhost}
        nonSecurePort: ${host.instance.port:8080}
        leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 5 #default is 30, recommended to keep default
        metadataMap:
          instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
      client:
        serviceUrl:
          defaultZone: http://(eurekaServerHost):8761/eureka/

    server:
      port: ${host.instance.port:8080}
```

So now my question is shall I use peer1 or peer2 as EurekaServerHost in the client application.yml?

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use a comma separated list of peers in `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone`.

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://<peer1host>:<peer1port>/eureka,http://<peer2host>:<peer2port>/eureka
```

Comment: This is not working for my case. I am putting couple of Eureka hosts as comma seperated list in eureka client application. However it is only registering with the first one in the list. Please help.

Comment: from https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Understanding-Eureka-Peer-to-Peer-Communication 

"Once the server starts receiving traffic, all of the operations that is performed on the server is replicated to all of the peer nodes that the server knows about. If an operation fails for some reason, the information is reconciled on the next heartbeat that also gets replicated between servers."

Comment: @spencergibb - Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53955173/eureka-replication-not-showing-the-dashboard ?

Comment: @spencergibb: Can we give the URL for a load-balancer setup in front of eureka instances? In this way I don't have to modify my service URL every time a new Eureka instance is added. Though I tried, but replication is not working. You can refer to my setup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489749/microservices-not-registering-on-all-eureka-instances)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using eureka behind a load-balancer.

Comment: @spencergibb Can you please let me know any specific reason for it?

Comment: Eureka was built in a way that every client needs to know about every peer

Comment: It works great for me, except that whenver the first instance is down, the microservice (which uses Eureka to find the config server) launches an ERROR that causes it to stop.

The ERROR is due to a missing property @Value, which has to be retrieved from the config server.

How is it possible that the ms doesn't try all urls in defaultZone before trying to autowire properties?