# Eureka doesn't replicate its registry info to all servers

Tags: netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I deployed 3 Eureka servers. A peers with B, B peers with C, C peers with A. I also have a client with `eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=Eureka A's address`. When I started my client, things were wired:

Eureka A and B had my client's registry info, but server C got nothing. I waited for 5mins server C still got nothing. I think server C should have client's registry info because server C peers with Server A, so C will sync registry with A. What's wrong here?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to list the other server in each server's configuration.
So in your case in each registry there should 2 entries for the defaultZone.
In the clients you can also specify multiple servers with the same property.

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://<peer1host>:<peer1port>/eureka,http://<peer2host>:<peer2port>/eureka
```

As discussed here:
[How to config multiple Eureka Servers from client in Spring Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850232/how-to-config-multiple-eureka-servers-from-client-in-spring-cloud)

Extra info: 
http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_peer_awareness