# HAProxy integration with Eureka

Tags: dns, haproxy, netflix-eureka, nameservers, cloud-foundry

Is it possible to integrate `HAProxy` with `Eureka`, so that `Eureka Service Registry` serves as list of available servers for `HAProxy` to load balance? 
 As per [this](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#5.3) `HAProxy` can be configured to dynamically get list of available servers using name-servers? Can Eureka serve the purpose of a name-server?

Comment: Do you have multiple Eureka instances, that you want to access? Is that your use case? what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: If you have multiple Eureka instances, you can use Eureka peering.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850232/how-to-config-multiple-eureka-servers-from-client-in-spring-cloud

Comment: As explained above, I want to check if `HAProxy` can get list of servers from `Eureka`? Other words, Can `HAPProxy` be treated as eureka-client? If Not, can eureka be treated as `Name-Server`?

Comment: I don't think it works that way. 
Eureka is an app, just like any other app on CF. So, the ip address for an instance of Eureka is, first local (i.e. 10.xxx), and second ephemeral. If that instance crashes for some reason, PCF will spin a new instance with a new ip.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late but still:

You can scrape app hostnames and ports from eureka's rest api and dynamically update your haproxy config and then reload.

1. cronjob/systemd-timer to periodically call your config generation
   script
2. systemctl reload haproxy.service
3. profit