# configure Registry to run in peer-aweraness mode or form the cluster so that I can get scalability and fault tolerance?

Tags: jhipster, spring-cloud-netflix, jhipster-registry

Can we configure Registry to run in peer-awareness mode or form the cluster so that I can get scalability and fault tolerance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to config multiple Eureka Servers from client in Spring Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850232/how-to-config-multiple-eureka-servers-from-client-in-spring-cloud)

Comment: JHipster contains other modules apart from Eureka. Will I be able to create cluster just by making registry peer aware?

Comment: Yes registry is also a spring cloud config server which can be clustered depending on backend, for git it should work as the repo is cloned locally. For dashboards, it should work aso as it is stateless and queries target microservices.